# Rust: substrate node template build error

Tags: rust, substrate

I have been following these instructions:

- https://substrate.dev/docs/en/knowledgebase/getting-started/
- https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/create-your-first-substrate-chain/setup

I get the following error after trying to run this code:

```
cd substrate-node-template
# NOTE: you should always use the `--release` flag
cargo build --release
# ^^ this will take a while!
```

This is the error, any idea what's happening?:

```
  Downloaded approx v0.3.2
  Downloaded parity-db v0.2.3
error: failed to parse manifest at /Users/ilyssaevans/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/parity-db-0.2.3/Cargo.toml


Caused by:
  failed to parse the version requirement `0.11 ` for dependency `parking_lot`

Caused by:
  expected comma after minor version number, found '\t'
zsh: command not found: #
```

Comment: On the face of it, there's a problem with the copy of `parity-db v0.2.3` that you downloaded — or possibly with that version in the GitHub repository.

Comment: Please update paritydb 
If that doesn't work remove cargo cache and reinstall everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run

cargo update -p parity-db

If this doesn't help please clear cargo cache and reinstall