# Substrate rust developer environment error

Tags: bash, shell, rust, substrate

I restarted my Rust installation (manually) after running into some errors when restarting. The original thread is here: [Rust: substrate node template build error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68705505/rust-substrate-node-template-build-error)

The error comes from running this line:

`curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh`

Now I get this error, I am not sure how to proceed. Any suggestions on how to move forward? This was from the manual Rust configurations instructions on: https://substrate.dev/docs/en/knowledgebase/getting-started/

````
   default host triple: x86_64-apple-darwin
     default toolchain: stable (default)
               profile: default
  modify PATH variable: yes

1) Proceed with installation (default)
2) Customize installation
3) Cancel installation
>

error: could not amend shell profile: '/Users/ilyssaevans/.bash_profile': could not write rcfile file: '/Users/ilyssaevans/.bash_profile': Permission denied (os error 13)```
````

Comment: Seems to be a permission issue but how do I fix this so it compiles successfully?

Comment: Looks like just giving write permissions should help you go though. I think you can use chmod with no problems on mac
`chmod o+w /Users/ilyssaevans/.bash_profile`

Comment: Thanks a ton, now getting this: ```chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/ilyssaevans/.bash_profile: Operation not permitted```

Do I need to include o+w+a (admin?)

Comment: I would say try running it again as sudo and see what is the outcome.

But at this point this is no longer a substrate issue

Comment: nothing gives (see chat). Discussing options for installing Linux and starting the process all over

Comment: I restarted on a PC with ubuntu.